# Why does a complete DynamoDB Object Mapper for JPA support NOT exist?

Tags: jpa, amazon-dynamodb

There are Object Mappers for JPA support for NoSQL databases like Mongo, Couch in [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/), [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/). But, I could not able to find any reliable and actively developed framework for Dynamodb.

I looked [spring-data-dynamodb](https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb), but it is stated that:

> Due to external time and project commitments, I'm no longer able to continue active development of this project as of January 2016. Thank you to everyone involved in shaping the project over the past few years and thanks to all those who have raised issues and submitted pull requests over the time.

This lack of support causes model integration problems with widely used Java MVC frameworks.

Could you please explain me the technical details, why there is not a complete Dynamodb Object Mapper for JPA support?

Comment: Spring Data is not a JPA implementation, so not relevant to discussing JPA support for a datastore, and Spring Data MongoDB/DynamoDB are absolutely nothing to do with JPA API. There is no JPA support for DynamoDB maybe because nobody has had the time to do it? All 4 main JPA implementations (DataNucleus, Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA) are open source, so anybody could contribute to them. DynamoDB is not freely available, so less likely to attract someone to support it. JPA is designed for RDBMS only. And on it goes.

Comment: @BillyFrost Thanks for the reply, I edited the question.